# Stay images while app running on libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am prety new on LibGdx but tring to learn.anyway here is the my problem.
I have heart icons which is represent the life of the user.It starts the 3 heart icons positioned side by side.My problem is ,I cant show those icons while App running.It only shows at the begining of the game and suddenyly disappers.How can I able to stay life icons(heart icons) on the game ,while running app.
Here is the my codes.

Game constructure

```
GameAreaScreen(final MyGdxGame game){

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();//400
        camWidh = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();//800
        cany=camHeight;
        camera.setToOrtho(false, camWidh, camHeight);
        iconSize=64f;
        canlar= new Array<Can>();
        canlar.add(new Can());canlar.add(new Can());canlar.add(new Can());
        _game= game;
        create(); 
    }
```

and my rendered

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        //render
        GL20 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL20();
         gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        camera.update();

        // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
        // coordinate system specified by the camera.
        _game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        _game.batch.begin();
        _game.font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        _game.batch.draw(pointsbgImage,camWidh-iconSize, camHeight-iconSize);
        _game.font.draw(_game.batch,String.valueOf(dropsGathered), camWidh-iconSize/2f,camHeight-iconSize/2f );
        _game.batch.end();
        _game.batch.begin();
        for (Can eleman : canlar) {
               _game.batch.draw(eleman.canImageTexture, canx+iconSize,cany-iconSize);
                drawRect2(canx+iconSize, cany-iconSize, iconSize/2f, iconSize/2f, 1, eleman.canImageTexture);
                canx+=iconSize;

            }
        _game.batch.end();
   .......
   .......

}
```

and my Can class which represent the Life

```
public class Can  {

    public Texture canImageTexture;
    public Can(){
        canImageTexture=(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/heart.png")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
canx+=iconSize;
```

is the problem. It is increased to infinity which moves the icons to right outside the screen. reset canx to certain start value in the render() method

Comment: Thank you bro.İt works fine .I missed that.thank you again

Comment: Have u any idea how can I give effect to image when adding or removing like fade in fade out